# Is true != true, or is AccessViolationException strange

Tags: c#, exception, logic

Whilst writing code I ran into a strange situation where my `if` returns true, even if the test is clearly false. I have dumbed down the code to see if I am missing something, but the `throw AccessViolationException()` keeps executing.

```
bool valid = true;
if (valid != true)
{
    throw new AccessViolationException("WTF");
}
```

Does `AccessViolationException` have strange powers, or has my computer gone off the deep end?

Edit: The "dumbed down" means I took out all extra functions and this is the code that I was left with. These few lines are a copy and paste of what is in my application. This is my *real* code

Edit 2:
I cleaned the solution, rebuild, rebooted.

The code currently looks like this and I am still getting the same problem where the `if` returns true.

```
bool valid = true;
if (valid != true)
{
    throw new Exception("WTF");
}
```

Similar code in another function works as expected.
The above code is EXACTLY what is in my function at the moment.

Comment: Changed AccessViolationException to Exception. Still experiencing problem.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your *real* `if` condition.

Comment: Either that's not your actual code, or you bought your c# compiler and a human liver on the black market for 30 dollars.

Comment: Changed it to `if (true != true)` and it works as expected. Changed it back to `if (valid != true)` and the code acts weird again.

Comment: @walkhard, the code posted is what is currently in my app! This is the real if!

Comment: Maybe you suppose your real statement returns true but actually it goes to false somehow.. If you can post it, maybe we can find the problem.

Comment: Is `valid` a local variable, or a field? Is it being shared with some other thread?

Comment: @dcastro: Local, defined in the line above.

Comment: @AtronSeige Can you post the complete method?

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: This IS the complete code: `bool valid = true;
   if (valid != true)
   {
    throw new Exception("WTF");
   }'

Comment: @AtronSiege tested in VS2010 and it didn't throw any exception!

Comment: Ok... I think my PC has a hiccup. I will try a rebuild @x2. and after that a reboot. Before my computer rips this reality to shreds. Thanks for confirmation that it is just my pc.

Comment: Clean, Rebuild, Reboot. Nothing worked.

Comment: Can you give details of your configuration? What CPU and architecture, version of VS, framework version, and so forth? On VS2013 on Win7/x64 I can't reproduce.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: Intel i5 2.8. VS2012 (11.0.61030.00 Upd 4). Win 7/x64. But I think I resolved the symptom. I still have no idea what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough the answer is to delete the existing code (the variable declaration and following if statement). Recompile.
Insert the code again. Recompile.

I have no idea what caused this, but at least I can code again.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, that your code is not that, what is running on your computer.
For some strange reason the compiler does not compile your code (well), and some of your previous version runs.
Rebuilding (as mentioned in one comment) is a good try, but not sure it succeeds.
Instead:

1. exit Visual Studio
2. Delete "bin" and "obj" folders in your project directory
3. Open VS and your project, again
4. Comile, run, and be happy.

Comment: I can assure you that that is my code. The original code was far more interesting, but with the error I removed everything else from the code to determine what is going on. These lines of code are what I was left with.

Comment: I belive the code You posted here is the real code. Just tought the compiler "plays with you". 
For optimisation reasons the compiler does not compile everything everytime, just what has changed. Maybe the compiler doesn't recognised some of your changes.
If this is the issue, then deleting bin and obj will help.

Comment: I deleted the bin folder, but did not delete the obj folder. Doesn't a "clean solution" kill the obj folder? Anyway, I assume that the compiler got a bit confused. We all do.